# Create sfContext in symfony task without unnecessary things

Tags: symfony-1.4, task, swiftmailer

I use symfony 1.4. And I use task for email reporting, before retrieving sfMailer i create sfContext instance, but during creation symfony output this lines to the console:

```
>> sfPatternRouting Connect sfRequestRoute "sf_captchagd" (/captcha)
>> sfPatternRouting Match route "homepage" (/) for / with parameters array (  'module' => 'main',  'action' => 'index',)
```

As you can see, `sfContext` create routing stuff and probably other unnecessary things - i need just two things: partial templates and sfMailer instance thats all.
Here is the lines when i create `sfContext` instance:

```
sfContext::createInstance($this->configuration);
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Partial');
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a new evironment in your `factories.yml` and `settings.yml` with only the things you need. It doesn't need to have a php script in the web directory, only a definition in the `factories.yml` and `settings.yml` same as dev and test and stage environments. And when you load the context configuration use that environment. In your own mailer environment you can disable routing, cache, and other parts of the framework.